# How to nest a navigation page, within a Flyout page tab in .NET Maui?

Tags: navigation, maui

How to create a navigation page, nested in a flyout page in .net maui?

My app has a Flyout in the page with the following tabs [Dashboard, Report, Utilities].

Once navigating to their pages, each has numerous items that need navigation as well. For example ReportsPage has 5 buttons for Reports 1-5 (arbitrary names). I need to be able to click each ReportButton[1-5], that will navigate to their associated report page [ReportDetails], and then be able to navigate back to the previous page of ReportsPage, to allow me to select whichever of the 5 buttons again.

How can this be done, when App goes to AppShell, and then MainPage is set to Flyoutpage?

```cs
public partial class App : Application
    {
        public App()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            MainPage = new AppShell();

            Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(HomePage), typeof(HomePage));
            Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(EndOfMonthPage), typeof(EndOfMonthPage));
            Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(DashboardPage), typeof(DashboardPage));
            Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(ReportsPage), typeof(ReportsPage));
            Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(UtilitiesPage), typeof(UtilitiesPage));
        }
    }
```

```cs
public partial class AppShell : Shell
    {
        public AppShell()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            BindingContext = new FlyoutViewModel();
        }
    }
```

```xml
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Billing.SupportTool.M.App.View.ReportsPage"
             xmlns:model="clr-namespace:Billing.SupportTool.M.App.Model"
             xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:Billing.SupportTool.M.App.ViewModel"
             x:DataType="viewmodel:ReportViewModel"
             Title="{Binding Title}"
             x:Name="this">
    <!--TODO: Fix Binding Title in BaseViewModel-->

    <!-- TODO: Split again into 2 panes, for selected report to display to the right -->
    <Grid ColumnDefinitions="*,*"
          ColumnSpacing="5"
          RowDefinitions="*,Auto"
          RowSpacing="0">
        <CollectionView BackgroundColor="DimGray" 
                        Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
                        ItemsSource="{Binding Reports}"
                        SelectionMode="None">
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:Report">
                    <Button 
                        Text="{Binding Name}"
                        FontSize="13"
                        ImageSource="{Binding Image}"
                        HeightRequest="125" 
                        Padding="0"
                        HorizontalOptions="Fill"
                        Style="{StaticResource ButtonOutline}"
                        Clicked="OnReportClicked">
                    </Button>
                 </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>
    </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

```cs
public partial class ReportsPage : ContentPage
{
    public ReportsPage(ReportViewModel vm)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = vm;
    }

    private async void OnReportClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Wrap the nested page with a NavigationPage
        var navigationPage = new NavigationPage(new ReportDetailsPage());
        
        // Navigate to the nested page
        await Navigation.PushAsync(navigationPage);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't use a NavigationPage that way. [Maui NavigationPage doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/pages/navigationpage) has this warning: *"NavigationPage is incompatible with .NET MAUI Shell apps"*. Instead, make a single `ReportDetailsPage` that is capable of showing what any of the 5 buttons shows. Send it query parameter(s) to control what is shown. See `Maui shell navigation` doc.

Comment: You can check this [Flyout display options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/flyout#flyout-display-options) and set the ShellContent objects to be children of the FlyoutItem object.